# Why is it giving me a no index error? when all my indexes are fine in python?

Tags: python

The output is "list index put of range" whenever I run it.

I need to store each of the fields into their own list. So I should have three fields, one for rank, one for power, and one for the number of those cards.

This is the file, that is called "ranks.dat":

```
Admiral,30,1 General,25,1 Colonel,20,2 Major,15,2 Captain,10,2 Lieutenant,7,2 Sergeant,5,4 Corporal,3,6 Private,1,10
```

Here is my code:

```
numFile = open("ranks.dat", "r")

rankList = []
skillList = []
powerList = []

while True:
    text = numFile.readline()
    text = text.rstrip("\n")
    if text=="":
        break
    info = text.split(" ")
    rankList.append(info[0])
    skillList.append(int(info[1]))
    powerList.append(int(info[2]))

numFile.close()


print("Admiral\tGeneral\tColonel\tMajor\tCaptain\tLieutenant\tSergeant\tCorporal\tPrivate")
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Please update your question with the exact reason `it not working`. If the output is wrong, please update with the actual and expected. If there is an error please update with the full error traceback.

Comment: If the input is a single line, then you must split by spaces to get a list of records, each of which must then be split by commas to obtain the three fields.

Comment: @quamrana ok, I have changed it now.

Comment: @mkam if possible could you please write it out for me?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: What @quamrana means is to **copy and paste** the actual error message into your question, including all the traceback information.  Your edit isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data has one entry per line:

```
rankList = []
skillList = []
powerList = []

# recommended way to open and close a file
with open("ranks.dat", "r") as file:
    # iterate over every lines in the file
    for line in file.readlines(): 
        # unpack each lines
        rank, skill, power = line.split(',')

        rankList.append(rank)
        skillList.append(skill)
        powerList.append(power)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is contain some mistakes.

First of all it should not be inside a `while` loop, but (if at all) in `for line in text`.

Secondly, when you `split(" ")`, you get a list that every item in it contain string in form of `"RANK,SKILL,POWER"`. You should split it every comma, and then append the items to the lists.

And finally, i would highly recommend to check the validity of the input (like checking that there are three items in the splitted `info`).

Something like that:

```
rankList = []
skillList = []
powerList = []

fil = open("ranks.dat", "r")
data = fil.read()
fil.close()

for item in data.split():
      info = item.split(',')
      if len(info) != 3:
            continue
      rankList.append(info[0])
      skillList.append(int(info[1]))
      powerList.append(int(info[2]))

# and do whatever you want
```

It depend on the source of the file, but a complete and correct code will check first if the file exists, and if the values of the rank and skills and the power are valid